# Doctrine 2 findBy* return object

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to change `findBy*` method to return an object (my custom) with entities instead of an array?

Comment: `findBy*()` returns a set of entities, actually probably a `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection` object.  How can it return anything other than a collection?  Use `findOneBy()` if you know it to be a single and want an entity.

Comment: Sorry, I described it wrong. I want to use object becouse I want to have methods which can working with entities. Something like

`$this->doctrine->findById(array(1, 2, 3))->myCustomMehod();`

Comment: `->findBy(array(1, 2, 3))` will match up to 3 separate entities, so the returned object would have to be a collection.  If you write an extension to ArrayCollection, that takes an existing collection, then feed it the result from the `findBy()` call to the constructor and call your method on it.  If you make a custom repository, then you can make your own method that does the whole process in one move.  Which would be advisable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it and works perfect. But when I trying to call `myCustomMehod()` on reference (M:N) it doesn't works. Like `$this->doctrine->findOneById(1)->types->myCustomMehod();` (Fatal Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::myCustomMethod()). Is there any chance to make it work?

Comment: `findOneById()` should return the entity type of whatever repository you are working with.  The method should go in your entity if you are trying to call it from that.  What is `->types->` in aid of?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to said that types (it's property shortcut to method getTypes()) is instance of **Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection** (which Doctrine return in Many To Many association). I would like to use the myCustomMehod() here too (if it's possible) but I dont know how.

Comment: Well, I doubt there is a way of overriding that class.  Why do you need to do this?  Sounds like you are approaching the problem from the wrong angle.  Most likely a method that should be in a custom repository.

Comment: I need to convert data from entity to array pairs ('id' => 'name' for example) becouse i need use it into forms. I think that the simplest way is something like `$entities->fetchPairs('id', 'name')`. But I stuck at converting M:N associations.

Comment: Edit your question with a much more expanded idea of what you are trying to achieve, as I do not completely understand from that.  Then we can try and work out a solution.

Answer (score 13):

Use findOneBy instead of findBy. findOneBy is return as an object.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html

```
$obj = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository("VendorXXXBundle:EntityName")
    ->findOneBy(array $criteria)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better served writing a custom function in your entity repository.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my dirty, low-tech approach.

Your findBy* here:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository($entclass)->findBy($entFilter, array('id' => 'DESC'));
```

My one-liner conversion here:

```
$entitiesCollection= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($entities);
```

Then I confirmed I could use those handy ArrayCollection methods like last(), count(), contains(), etc.

```
var_dump($entitiesCollection->count(), $entitiesCollection); print \strftime('%c') . __FILE__ . __LINE__ . __FUNCTION__; die;
```